# Debugging MVC4 bundling with RTM

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-optimization, bundling-and-minification

So I finished developing a new mvc4 application with the rtm bits.

I deployed to a prod server and everything is working fine apart from the styling. Something is wrong with the bundle, I assume its an ordering problem or some file that's not rendered with the bundle.

How do I debug whats going on with the bundle to know what's going wrong? back in my development environment if I switch debug=false within the web.config I can replicate the issue I am having in prod so its not something wrong with that environment.

Thank you!!

Update. If I turn off the enableoptimizations via BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
The site on prod works ok however no minification of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think its an ordering problem, the order you see when EnableOptimizations = false will be the order you get in your bundle when optimizations are on.

You could also try turning off minification by changing all of your ScriptBundles to just be Bundles (which have no Transform), then you'll get the scripts bundled but not minified, and hopefully you can just debug the javascript.